# How to store data which is UI to MySQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my UI page, I have a tab called Acknowledged and I have set it to boolean value. How can i set those data into my MySQL Database?`

```
public static AlertModel into(NotificationAlertMessage item) {
AlertModel model = new AlertModel();
model.setAcknowledged(item.isAcknowledged());
model.setNotificationSent(item.isNotificationSent());

return model;
```

}

Here Acknowledged I have set it to boolean value

In my UI, Acknowledged Tab, if the checkbox is checked, I am printing it as true, else false. But how to store this boolean values into my database?`

Comment: As a tinyint (0 - false, 1 - true)

Comment: do you use hibernate as orm? if yes, it will do it for you, don't worry :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to persist data from UI to MySQL Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295640/how-to-persist-data-from-ui-to-mysql-database)